# Wanted to play DASH file with exoplayer in android app

Tags: android, exoplayer

I have successfully able to play `hls` file with exoplayer but need example to play DASH file. Please give me the sample or overview of it. So can able play it. Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
DataSource videoDataSource =
                new DefaultUriDataSource(context, bandwidthMeter, userAgent);
        ChunkSource videoChunkSource = new DashChunkSource(manifestFetcher,
                DefaultDashTrackSelector.newVideoInstance(context, true, filterHdContent),
                videoDataSource, new FormatEvaluator.AdaptiveEvaluator(bandwidthMeter), LIVE_EDGE_LATENCY_MS,
                elapsedRealtimeOffset, mainHandler, (DashChunkSource.EventListener) player, VideoPlayer.TYPE_VIDEO);
        ChunkSampleSource videoSampleSource =
                new ChunkSampleSource(videoChunkSource, loadControl,
                        MAIN_BUFFER_SEGMENTS * BUFFER_SEGMENT_SIZE, mainHandler, player,
                        VideoPlayer.TYPE_VIDEO);
        TrackRenderer videoRenderer =
                new MediaCodecVideoTrackRenderer(context, videoSampleSource,
                        MediaCodecSelector.DEFAULT, MediaCodec.VIDEO_SCALING_MODE_SCALE_TO_FIT,
                        5000,
                        drmSessionManager, true, mainHandler, player, 50);
```